# How do I read in a pointer to an object from a file?

Tags: c++

I know this program is long, but any help would be much appreciated. When I try to read in an object from a file, I always end up with a segmentation fault. I've commented the line where the problem is. It's under 'case d' in the switch statement.

The objects I'm writing out the text file is polymorphic, which might be part of why I'm getting segmentation faults, but I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "employee.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string command, choice, name;
  float wage, percent;
  int hours = 1;
  std::ofstream file;
  std::ifstream infile;
  std::vector<Employee*> database;

  while (command[0] != 'q')
  {
  clear();
  menu();
  std::cout << "Enter command: ";
  std::cin >> command;

  try
  {
    if(command.size() != 1)
      throw "Not a character.";
    else
    {
      switch(command[0])
      {
        case 'n':
          std::cout << "Enter the name of the new employee: ";
          //std::cin >> name;
          std::cin.clear();
          std::cin.ignore();
          getline(std::cin, name);
          std::cout << "Hourly (h) or salaried (s): ";
          std::cin >> choice;

          if(choice.size() != 1)
            throw "Not a valid choice.";
          else
            if(choice == "h")
            {
              std::cout << "Enter hourly wage: ";
              std::cin >> wage;

              if(!wage)
                throw "Not an option";
              else{
                Employee *emp = new PartTimeEmployee(wage, name);
                database.push_back(emp);
                continueWithProgram();
                break;
              }
            }else if(choice == "s")
            {
              std::cout << "Enter salaried wage: ";
              std::cin >> wage;

              if(!wage)
                throw "Not an option";
              else{
                Employee *emp = new FullTimeEmployee(wage, name);
                database.push_back(emp);
                continueWithProgram();
                break;
              }
            }else{
              throw "Not an option";
            }

        case 'c':
          if(database.size() < 1)
            throw "No employees in database.";
          else
          {
            for(int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++)
            {
              std::cout << "Enter number of hours worked by " << database[i]->getName() << ": ";
              std::cin >> hours;
              std::cout << "Pay: $" << database[i]->computePay(hours) << std::endl;
            }  
            continueWithProgram();             
          }
          break;

        case 'r':
          std::cout << "Enter percentage to increase: ";
          std::cin >> percent;
          std::cout << "\nNew Wages\n---------" << std::endl;
          for(int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++)
          {
            database[i]->raiseWage(percent);
            std::cout << database[i]->getName() << "\t\t" << "$" << database[i]->toString(database[i]->getWage()) << std::endl;
          }
          continueWithProgram();
          break;

        case 'p':
          std::cout << "\nEmployee Database: " << database[0]->count << " Personnel\n-----------------\n";
          for(int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++)
          {
            std::cout << database[i]->getName() << std::endl;
          }
          continueWithProgram();
          break;

        case 'd':
          infile.open("emp.txt", std::ios::in);
          Employee *temp;

          if(infile.is_open())
          {
            while(!infile.eof())
            {
              infile >> *temp; // PROBLEM IS HERE...
              database.push_back(temp);
            }
          }else{
            std::cout << "Error occured. File not found." << std::endl;
          }

          infile.close();
          std::cout << "*Data has been downloaded*" << std::endl;
          continueWithProgram();
          break;

        case 'u':
          file.open("emp.txt", std::ios::trunc);

          if(file.is_open()){
            for(int i = 0; i < database.size(); i++)
              file << *database[i];
          }

          file.close();
          std::cout << "*Data has been uploaded*\n";
          continueWithProgram();
          break;

        default:
          if(command[0] == 'q')
            break;
          else
          {
            throw "Not a command";
            break;
          }
      }
    }
  }catch(const char* message)
  {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
    continueWithProgram();
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    std::cout << "Error occured." << std::endl;
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
    continueWithProgram();
  }
}
  return 0;
}
```

______________________________________________________-

Header File:
*This is where the operator overload is, which I'm sure is not part of the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>

class Employee
{
protected:
  float wage;
  std::string name;

public:
  static int count;

  Employee(float wage, std::string name)
  {
    this->wage = wage;
    this->name = name;
    count++;
  }

  virtual float getWage() = 0;
  virtual void setWage(float wage) = 0;
  virtual float computePay(int hours = 0) = 0;
  virtual float raiseWage(float percent = 0) = 0;
  virtual std::string toString(int value) = 0;
  std::string getName(){return name;}
  void setName(std::string name){this->name = name;}
  friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream &out, Employee &emp);
  friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream &in, Employee &emp);
};

class FullTimeEmployee : public Employee
{
public:
  FullTimeEmployee(float annualSalary, std::string name) : Employee(annualSalary, name)
  {
    getWage();
  }

  float getWage() {return wage;}
  void setWage(float wage) {this->wage = wage;}
  float computePay(int hours = 0) {return (wage / 52);}
  std::string toString(int value){return std::to_string(value) + "/year";}
  float raiseWage(float percent = 0)
  {
      wage = wage + (wage * (percent / 100));
      return wage;
  }
};

class PartTimeEmployee : public Employee
{
public:
  PartTimeEmployee(float wage, std::string name) : Employee(wage, name)
  {
    getWage();
  }
  float getWage() {return wage;}
  void setWage(float wage) {this->wage = wage;}
  std::string toString(int value){return std::to_string(value) + "/hour";}
  float computePay(int hours)
  {
    if(hours <= 40)
      return wage * hours;
    else
    {
      hours -= 40;
      return ((wage * 40) + ((wage * 1.5) * hours));
    }
  }
  float raiseWage(float percent = 0)
  {
      wage = wage + (wage * (percent / 100));
      return wage;
  }
};

std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream &out, Employee &emp)
{
  out << emp.name << std::endl << emp.wage << std::endl;
  return out;
}

std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream &in, Employee &emp)
{
  in >> emp.name; 
  in >> emp.wage;
  return in;
}

int Employee::count = 0;

void menu()
{
  std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "|Commmands: n - New Employee      |" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "|           c - Compute Paychecks |" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "|           r - Raise Wages       |" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "|           p - Print Records     |" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "|           d - Download Data     |" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "|           u - Upload Data       |" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "|           q - Quit              |" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;
}

void clear() {std::cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";}

int continueWithProgram()
{
    std::string anw;

    while(anw[0] != 'y' || anw[0] != 'Y')
    {
        std::cout << "\nDo you want to continue?(y/n) ";
        std::cin >> anw;
        return 0;
        if(anw.size() != 1)
        {
            throw "Not a character";
        }else if (anw[0] == 'n' || anw[0] == 'N')
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: It doesn't work otherwise, though.

Comment: I didn't read the full code but you are not allocating space for your `Employee *temp`, do you? So `Employee *temp = new Employee` might solve the problem.

Comment: Employee is an abstract class, so that doesn't work either. I'm writing out subclasses of Employee to the file.

Comment: If `Employee` is an abstract type, you probably need a function that can figure out what the actual type is, then construct and return one of those.  I haven't read all your code so maybe you're already doing some of the work in `operator>>`.

Comment: You can't read pointers from a file, because the address space you read them back into may not even support the pointer value that was written. This implies that it was pointless to written the pointers to the file in the first place. This is one of many reasons why we have serialization libraries instead of just the ill-conceived `fread()` and `fwrite()` methods. Use one.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add subtype information (Ex: 'f' or 'p', denoting partime and fulltime) somewhere in your file-format. If you really want do deserialize a Pointer from the file you might change both operators. 
(However I strongly recommend to use an other approach and fix memory leaks):

**`operator<<`** should first print an extra line consisting of just one character denoting the subtype of Employ that is serialized.

```
using PEmployee = *Employee;

std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream &in, PEmployee &emp)
{
  char subType;
  float wage;
  std::string name;

  in >> subType;
  in >> name;                // FIXIT - we suspect file in not eof
  in >> wage;

  if(subType == 'f')
    emp = new FullTimeEmploy(wage, name);
  else
    emp = new PartTimeEmploy(wage, name); // FIXIT: we suspect subType == 'p'

  return in;
}
```

And in the `while`-Loop beneath  `case 'd':` you should call the new operator by `infile >> temp;`
I hope this works and answers your question.

**I do not recommend this approach**, calling `new` as side-effect from an operator rises the question who (which part of the Prog) is responsible for cleaning up (i.e. calling `delete`). It might work in small Progs but usually it will results in a mess.

**Memory leaks:** If you use `new` and `delete`, be always aware where in Your Prog the allocated memory will be freed. It is not done by the Run-time environment, C++ is not a managed language. HINT: `std::vector<Employee*>` wont call delete on the stored pointers, it just frees its workload (`Employee*`). It's the pointer itself not the pointee, i.e. the Object you accuired with `new` .

PS: 
A more straight forward aproach is to change only the `operator<<` and evaluate the subtype inside the `while`-Loop beneath  `case 'd':` First read the subtype-char, `switch` subtype, create the according subclass (Ex: `temp = new PartTimeEmployee();` and call the unchanged `operator>>` with the newly created `temp`.

For this approach you'll need standart Constructors like `PartTimeEmployee::PartTimeEmployee();` for all your subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I only have about a couple of weeks worth of experience with C++, so this information was very helpful.

Comment: If this is the case, you should vote my answer and accept it as solution THX - Xantopp